# HTML button to submit form with popup

Tags: html, button

I have this code that submits a form and sends a mail, and it opens a different page saying successful:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Then I also have this code which is a sexy button that pops up a message that the mail has been sent (even though it hasn't):

```
<a href="submit-message.html" class="nicdark_marginbottom20_iphoneland nicdark_marginbottom20_iphonepotr nicdark_mpopup_ajax nicdark_outline white nicdark_btn nicdark_bg_bluedark medium title">Submit</a>
```

How do I combine the code so that the mail sends with the sexy button and I get the popup, instead of landing on a new page?

Comment: Neither of these elements is responsible for the presentation or the behaviour you are attributing to them. In the former case the `input[type="submit"]` is triggering the `action` attribute in its parent `form` and in the latter case the presentation is being handled by `css` and the behaviour is being handled by `javascript`.

Comment: That would explain why me shuffling the code together in 29 different ways hasn't made a difference... My action runs a contact.php file, do I then add the submit-message.html in the PHP file? I tried that but very possibly did it wrong...

Comment: You will launch a popup (either on the current page or on the form destination page) via javascript. If you want to launch the popup and _then_ go to the destination page, you can use an `onsubmit` javascript event listener, eg: `my-form.addEventListener('submit', launchMyPopup, false);`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to confirm the email sending, after which pop-up your so called sexy button.

```
<form method="POST" action="/your/path/to/php/file">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="someFunction();">
</form>

<a id="href_id" href="submit-message.html" class="nicdark_marginbottom20_iphoneland nicdark_marginbottom20_iphonepotr nicdark_mpopup_ajax nicdark_outline white nicdark_btn nicdark_bg_bluedark medium title">Submit</a>


<script type="application/javascript">
    function someFunction() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'route/to/php/file',
            data: {
                // data goes here
            },
            cache: false,
            headers: {
                // headers(if any) fo here
            },
            success: function(){
                $('#href_id').show();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

---

The php file may look something like this:

```
if(mail ($to, $subject, $message, $additional_headers = null, $additional_parameters = null)) {
  return true;
}
```

---

Now, clearly this is not a complete code and should not be taken as such, this is mearly a pointing in the right direction of sorts.

I'm using jQuery here simply because I'm more familiar with it, but all this can be done in pure javascript, there's no real need to use jQuery if you don't want to.

---

Read more about [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX), [PHP and Ajax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm).

---

As a final note, the logic is as such:

- Do an ajax call in the front-end
- Send email in backend using PHP(or your language of choice)
- Return a response that confirms or not that the email has been sent
- Based on that response display the pop-up